# JSF digital clock

Tags: java, jsf-2

What would be the best way to implement a digital clock in JSF 2.0? Is there a lib or component available or should I implement it myself? In the latter case, what would be the best way to implement it? The clock only should - obviously- be refreshed automatically on the page when a minute goes by. I wish not to use JavaScript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are dead set against using JavaScript, then you will have to do it using Flash or a Java Applet.

Comment: Since JavaScript would be the obvious solution here - as it would remove the need to refresh the whole page every minute - you should probably explain why don't want to use JavaScript.

Comment: JavaScript may sometimes be forbidden by the specification of a client. If you just refresh the whole page once a minute with f.e. meta tag you add an output text which prints hour and minute. You can get the from the java core like Calendar. But.. JSF uses Javascript extensively. So in case it is forbidden why do you use it?

Comment: I'm using templates in my JSF pages. The clock however should not be displayed on every page. The <body> tags are in a 'main template'. Only the content between the body tags is specified in other JSF pages that use this 'main template'. As far as I know I'll need <body onload="showTime()"> to activate the code for the clock. But then I'd be activating the JavaScript on pages where it shouldn't be activated. Or is there a way without using the onload trigger event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What would be the best way to implement a digital clock in JSF 2.0? Is there a lib or component available or should I implement it myself?*

No JSF component comes to mind. You'd need to implement it yourself.

---

> *In the latter case, what would be the best way to implement it? The clock only should - obviously- be refreshed automatically on the page when a minute goes by. I wish not to use JavaScript.*

Use JavaScript. There is really no better/easier way. Plus, there are lot of ready-to-use examples available on the internet.

---

> *As far as I know I'll need `<body onload="showTime()">` to activate the code for the clock. But then I'd be activating the JavaScript on pages where it shouldn't be activated. Or is there a way without using the onload trigger event?*

Just put a

```xml
<script>window.onload = functionName;</script>
```

somewhere in the document. It'll work equally good. You can also just do

```xml
<script>functionName();</script>
```

as long as that appears *after* the HTML DOM element representing the clock.

Answer (score 0):

Without javascript, the HTML header Meta tags

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=".."  />
```

is the only method that comes to my mind,

Using that you can reload the page every second, but it is an ugly solution.

Otherwise:

- Javascript (everybodys favorite)
- Flash (no Javascript)
- Java Applets (yes they still exist and hey no javascript).

I'd strongly suggest using Javascript, since a no Javascript policy and JSF makes no sense. This would even deny simple Components like HTMLCommandlinks, since those cannot be used without Javascript, just take a look at all the Javascript your JSF implementation actually creates.

Answer (score 0):

you can use primefaces, it has done many things for you.
see:http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/clock.jsf